# I have a simple question about linked list in c

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a simple question in linked list.

As i know if there are head node, node1 and node2, head node points node1, node1 points node2 and node2 points NULL.

But is it possible that node2 points node1, node1 points head node and head node points NULL??

Comment: It is possible -- you seem to be looking for a [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list).

Comment: In what sense "possible"? It's possible in that you can write code to make this happen. It's possible that you have backwards links. It's not possible in the sense that these pointers would violate the rules for a standard forward linked list.

Comment: There is no linked list library in C standard library, It depends of your node struct. Could you share your node struct for your question become clear?

Comment: If the head node points to `NULL`, then your linked list is empty, seen from that node. It's a matter of definition. You might say: yes, but seen from node2 the list is not empty. I might ask: then why did you call that last node the head node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is bit unclear what you are asking, but I think i can clear things up for you.

there are two major implementation of linked lists:

### uni-directional

each node holds a value and pointer to the `Next` node
The list wrapper points to the 1stNode
the last node points to NULL

e.g.
[Node1Val | next] --> [Node2Val | next] --> NULL

### bi-directional (a.k.a Doubly Linked List)

each node holds a value and two pointers:

- one to the `next` node in the list.
- second to the `previous` node in the list.

e.g.
NULL <-- [prev | Node1Val | next] <--> [prev | Node2Val | next] --> NULL

> ### Note
>
> theoretically, there can be Cycles in a linked list, but it is not very useful to call it a linked list.
> Those don't play much in real life applications, and show up only in Job-Interviews and silly questions.
>
> e.g.
> --> [Node1Val | next] --> [Node2Val | next] __
> \___________________________________/
> :: tried to draw a looping arrow to the first.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is called a doubly linked list where every node has a pointer to its predecessor and successor.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/doubly-linked-list/

The beauty and peril of C is you, the programmer, decides how it should be declared. Very abstractly you could call the tail node head and this convention would hold.

Answer (score 0):

This is called doubly linked list you can find an example here
http://linuxandc.com/doubly-linked-list/